# Ruby .gets doesn't work

Tags: ruby, sublimetext2, user-input

I'm trying to get simple user input in Ruby, but I can't get it working. I'm using the `gets` method, but the program never stops to ask me for input. I'm using Sublime Text 2 as my text editor, and I run the program in it, too (if this makes a difference).

Here's my code:

```
puts "What is your name?"
name = gets 
puts "Hello " + name + ". How are you?"
```

And here's the error (and output) given to me:

```
C:/Users/Sten Sootla/Desktop/Ruby workspace/exercise.rb:3:in `+': can't convert nil into String (TypeError)
from C:/Users/Sten Sootla/Desktop/Ruby workspace/exercise.rb:3:in `'
What is your name?
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

Why doesn't the program stop to ask me for input?

Comment: try it in `IRB` not in editor.. Code is perfect.

Comment: Yes, it works in irb. But why doesn't it work in the editor?

Comment: I guess that sublime text ruby interpreter doesn't allow for input..

Comment: beacuse `get` can prompt and take input from the editor when you will run it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I understand it. `gets` and `puts` are instance methods of `IO`, and the default `IO`s are `$stdout` and `$stdin`.

Calls to gets/puts will only be effective if the translator is capable of handling stdout/in e.g. IRB

If you run a ruby file from bash it works too.

io_test.rb

```
puts gets
```

in bash

```
ruby io_test.rb
```

Then it will "put" into stdout whatever it "gets" from stdin.

Answer (score 7):

Try using `$stdin.gets` instead of just a plain `gets`, this will force the input to come from stdin

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run code within ST2, check out the [`SublimeREPL`](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL) plugin, available through [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control). While you can use `IRB`, its main Ruby interface is through [`pry`](https://github.com/pry/pry), which is a lot more powerful. You can use it as a classic REPL (think Clojure or LISP), and you can also transfer your code from one tab into the running REPL in another tab by selection, line range, or block.

Interestingly, your code above works in `IRB` for me, but not `pry` for some reason - it's reading my `$EDITOR` environment variable, which is set to `subl -w` but failing with `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - subl -w`. Strange...

At any rate, I highly highly recommend SublimeREPL, as it's a really powerful tool, and is self-contained within ST2, so you don't have to keep flipping back and forth to your terminal, saving and reloading your programs.